# Why does Postman format "null=null" into my REST endpoint?

Tags: rest, http, postman, urlencode

I am making a REST GET call to our company's SharePoint. The "raw" endpoint in ascii is:

```html
https://{myCompany}.sharepoint.com/sites/{mySite}/_api/web/getbytitle('myList')/Items?&filter=Title eq 234
```

Now, given the special characters, I would of expected a URL Encoding (percent encoding) to:

```html
https://{myCompany}.sharepoint.com/sites/{mySite}/_api/web/getbytitle('myList')/Items%3F%26filter%3DTitle eq 234
```

However, Postman's code snippet gives me:

```html
https://{myCompany}.sharepoint.com/sites/{mySite}/_api/web/getbytitle('myList')/Items?null=null&filter=Title eq 234
```

The request works, however I don't understand the formatting that is occurring and would apricate an explanation. Specifically, how it is:

`Items?&filter=Title eq 234` = `Items?null=null&filter=Title eq 234`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Query Parameters

This is definitely not a url encoding issue.  This is another parameter added to the query string where the name is null and the associated value is null.  Please take a screenshot of your *Params* tab in Postman.  I have a suspicion it will look as follows

[image: Screenshot]

In  which case just uncheck the parameter or remove it outright.  This may have happened as a result of having a checked, but blank, parameter on that page.